What game is this/is it based on anything?
There's a Chinese show on Netflix called The King's Avatar (it may have been removed by now).
The show is about a group of five or so that start an eSports team in the most competitive game in the world, Glory.
Here's a (low-res) photo:

Here you can watch a 5 minute 30 second video of a fight in the game.
It's pretty unlikely it's a real game, given the ridiculous amount of movement that's required by the human players to make the in-game characters do certain attacks, and that half the time they spam keys that don't appear to do anything.
But is it based on a real game(s)?

It's likely a made-up game, also because the character depicted is the digital version of the actor.
Also, from Reddit:

If Glory was a real game and I had the gaming equipment at home I would be the first to sign up.

In the same Reddit one user thinks that Glory is based on Phantasy Star Online 2.
